# R Setter method in class

Tags: r, class, setter

When I write a setter method in a class, the setter method does not change the value. I just cannot find the error here.

```
point <- function(x,y){
  structure(class = "point", list(
    # attributes
    x = x,
    y = y,
    # methods
    get_x = function() paste("(", x,",",y,")"),
    set_x = function(x,y){ self.x = x; self.y =  y}

  ))}


> p <- point(0,1)
> p$get_x()
[1] "( 0 , 1 )"

> p$set_x(6,5)
> p$get_x()

[1] "( 0 , 1 )"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow this change to your code.
In function `set_x`, it is the values of variables `x` and `y` created in function `point` that are assigned new values with `<<-`, not the `x` and `y` that exist in the `.GlobalEnv`.

```
point <- function(x, y){
  structure(class = "point", list(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    get_x = function() paste("(", x,",",y,")"),
    set_x = function(x, y){ 
      x <<- x
      y <<- y
    }
  ))
}

x <- 0
y <- 1

p <- point(0,1)
p$get_x()
#[1] "( 0 , 1 )"

p$set_x(6,5)
p$get_x()
#[1] "( 6 , 5 )"

x
#[1] 0

y
#[1] 1
```

Comment: If I call the set_x function using your solution, p$x and p$y still retain the old values 1 and 0.

Comment: @scs I am not seeing a way to solve that right now. Maybe you can find some inspiration in R-intro.pdf, section 10.7 Scope, the `open.account` example.

Comment: @Barradas: In R, it is not necessary to define attributes/member variables as these values are kept in the parameters. So the definitions of x and y can simply be omitted in the class definition to avoid confusion. The open.account example illustrates this.

Comment: @scs Yes, I believed you wanted them returned by function `point`. In which case they would be members of `p` and not accessible by `p$set_x`.